# AMP: why are files with .amp.html extensions not displayed on linux hosting?

Tags: html, linux, hosting, project, amp-html

I recently converted all the web pages of my website into amp. I rename them all in (.amp.html). I took care to test each page with the amp tester: https://ampbyexample.com/playground/
i also bought a domain name that points to https, a linux hosting at godaddy. Only here, when I send the files to the extensions (.amp.html) nothing is displayed on the domain name. By cons when I rename all files in (.html) simply, the website is displayed. My question is, why are files with .amp.html extensions not displayed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes down to webserver configuration, and likely has two issues.

The first is that you're probably expecting a default document to appear when you don't request a specific one.  For example, `http://example.com/`... the path here is just `/`, but a web server will commonly load `index.html` from disk.  Chances are, your web server is not configured to load `index.amp.html` from disk.

The second issue may come down to a bad MIME type configuration.  It's important that `text/html; charset=utf-8` be sent as the `Content-Type` response header value for your HTML files.

If you have control over your webserver, you can reconfigure it yourself.  You didn't tell us what server you're using, so we can't tell you specifically how to do that.  If you don't have control over your webserver, you'll have to take it up with your hosting provider... GoDaddy.  Or, just name things `.html` and you'll be fine!